# What is the map induced by Frobenius on the cohomology group $H_{fppf}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, flat-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective curve of degree $p$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$, where $k$ is a field of charcteristic $p>0$. $X$ may not be reduced. I'm trying to compute $H_{fppf}^1(X, \alpha_p)$ using the following exact sequence

\begin{equation}
0\to \alpha_p \to \mathbb G_a \stackrel{(-)^p}\to \mathbb G_a \to 0\tag{1}
\end{equation}

But I've not able figure out what is the map induced on $H_{fppf}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a)$ by the Frobenius morphism? What is the map here?

Since,  $H_{fppf}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a) = H_{zar}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a  )$, I used the following exact sequence to compute $H_{zar}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a  )$
$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal O(-p) \rightarrow  \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{2}} \rightarrow i_{*} \mathcal O_{X} \rightarrow 0$$

here $i:X \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^{2}$ is closed immersion of $X$ in to 
$\mathbb{P}^2_k$.

From this we get,$H_{fppf}^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a) = H^2_{zar}(\mathbb P^{2}_k,O(-p)) $

So, may be question can be rephrased as the action of Frobenius on $H^2_{zar}(\mathbb P^{2}_k,O(-p)) $? How can I find the map here? Any kind of help in approaching these questions will be very much appreciated.

PS. I posted this math.stackexachange I don't think it got much attention

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773115/what-is-the-map-induced-by-frobenius-on-the-cohomology-group-h-fppf1x-mat

Comment: See the section on the Hasse invariant in chapter IV 4 of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, esp. Prop. 4.21. The map induced by Frobenius on  $H^2(\mathbf{P}^2, \mathcal{O}(-p))$ should be given in the standard basis by taking appropriate coefficients of $f^{p-1}$ where $f$ is the equation of $X$. Hope this helps.